# Can anyone explain this more clearly?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I'm new to CGT so i might need help but could anyone simplify this and explain it to me please-
"set f ⊕ f = 0 for
any f. (A nice correspondence can be made if we think back to the original
game of Nim: if you take any two equal size Nim piles and add their values
via binary addition without carry, you always obtain zero!)
From this, it immediately follows that F, ⊕ constitute an abelian group
where every element is of order 2. If F were finite, then the remainder of
our argument would follow directly from the fundamental theorem of finitely
generated abelian groups, which states that G must then be a direct sum of
additive groups of integers modulo k; however, since this group must be of
order 2, all the k’s must be 2 (since if there were a k > 2 then there would be
an element of that order, and not of order 2.) When F is infinite, then the
conclusion is still guaranteed since any group of bounded order (i.e., where
there is a bound on the orders of all group elements) is a direct sum of cyclic
groups [10].
Recall that the additive group of integers mod 2 is simply 1-bit binary
addition without carry, so the above characterization can be interpreted as
F being the binary sum mod 2 without carry of integers. Thus, we get the
basic structure of the Sprague-Grundy theory from a decomposition theorem
about groups and the mystery of the base 2 is revealed."
I dont properly understand the fundamental theory of finitely generated abelian groups so if you could simplify that that would be helpful.

Comment: Groups are studied in abstract algebra, in the subfield of "group theory". Whatever it is you're reading is assuming you've already taken a course in abstract algebra (or at least worked through a significant portion of a textbook on it), so that you're at a point where you already know something called "[the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification)" (note that it's a theorem, not a theory). I would recommend either getting another source for CGT if you don't want to wait until you know group theory